# Masstransit subscriber performance

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I use `Masstransit (version 3.2.4)` with `RabbitMq (version 3.6.0)`.

**My Publisher:**

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => {
        x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });
    });

    var busHandle = bus.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        bus.Publish(new Message() { Text = i.ToString() });
    }

    busHandle.Stop();
    Console.ReadKey();
```

**My Subsriber:**

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
    {
        var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });

        x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestSubscriber", e =>
          e.Handler<Message>(a => 
          {
              Console.WriteLine(a.Message.Text);
              return Task.FromResult(0);
          }));
    });

    var busHandle = bus.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
    busHandle.Stop();
```

When i the run Publisher/Subscriber and i look at the statistics. **Publish** is about `7406` messages per second and **Subscribe** is about `2531` messages per second. I don't understand why is the speed of subscriber about three time less than speed of publisher. Is it normal and how can I increase the speed of the subscriber?

[image]

Comment: Create more subscriber threads?

Comment: I tried to set the value for `x.UseConcurrencyLimit(100)`  to 100 threads and more, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Tried PrefetchCount?

Comment: Remove the Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Chris Patterson, If remove `Console.WriteLine`, speed of subscriber is about `5200` messages per second.

Comment: What is the speed of the publish/subscribe (messages per second) is the norm (average) for RabbitMq?

Comment: Depends if you're using durable messages or not. With the standalone MassTransit.Benchmark project, I can usually do 12,000 streaming messages a second non-durable without publisher confirmation. That's in a single box with a single app and a single connection to RMQ.